# Use log4j logging jersey 2.25

Tags: java, jersey, log4j, jersey-2.0

I am using Log4j logging.

As Jersey 2.25 uses java util logging, Requests and responses are not getting logged

In Older jersey, I had custom filter for this.

Does any one have idea to fix it.

```
 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;

 import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
 import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

 import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
 import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
 import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
 import org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter;
 import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException;
 import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
 import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse;
 import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
 import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ContainerResponseWriter;



 public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
 /**
 * If true the request and response entities (if present) will not be logged. If false the request
 * and response entities will be logged.
 * <p>
 * The default value is false.
 */
 public static final String FEATURE_LOGGING_DISABLE_ENTITY =
 "com.sun.jersey.config.feature.logging.DisableEntitylogging";

 private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(LoggingFilter.class.getName());

 private static final String NOTIFICATION_PREFIX = "* ";

 private static final String REQUEST_PREFIX = "> ";

 private static final String RESPONSE_PREFIX = "< ";

 private final Log logger;

 private @Context HttpContext hc;

 private @Context ResourceConfig rc;

 private long id = 0;

 /**
 * Create a logging filter logging the request and response to a default JDK logger, named as the
 * fully qualified class name of this class.
 */
 public LoggingFilter() {
 this(LOGGER);
 }

 /**
 * Create a logging filter logging the request and response to a JDK logger.
 *
 * @param logger the logger to log requests and responses.
 */
 public LoggingFilter(Log logger) {
 this.logger = logger;
 }

 private synchronized void setId() {
 if (hc.getAttribute("request-id") == null) {
 hc.setAttribute("request-id", Long.toString(++id));
 }
 }

 private StringBuilder prefixId(StringBuilder b) {
 b.append(hc.getAttribute("request-id").toString()).append(" ");
 return b;
 }

 public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
 setId();

 final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
 printRequestLine(b, request);
 printRequestHeaders(b, request.getRequestHeaders());

 if (rc.getProperties().get(FEATURE_LOGGING_DISABLE_ENTITY)) {
 logger.debug(b.toString());
 return request;
 } else {
 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
 try {
 if (in.available() > 0) {
 ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

 byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
 try {
 String contentType = request.getRequestHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
 if (contentType != null && (contentType.startsWith("image")
 || contentType.equals("application/octet-stream"))) {
 b.append("Binary content: " + contentType).append("\n");
 } else {
 printEntity(b, requestEntity);
 }
 } catch (Exception e) {
 logger.warn("Failed to log request", e);
 }
 request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
 }
 return request;
 } catch (IOException ex) {
 throw new ContainerException(ex);
 } finally {
 logger.debug(b.toString());
 }
 }
 }

 private void printRequestLine(StringBuilder b, ContainerRequest request) {
 prefixId(b).append(NOTIFICATION_PREFIX).append("Server in-bound request").append('\n');
 prefixId(b).append(REQUEST_PREFIX).append(request.getMethod()).append(" ")
 .append(request.getRequestUri().toASCIIString()).append('\n');
 }

 private void printRequestHeaders(StringBuilder b, MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : headers.entrySet()) {
 String header = e.getKey();
 for (String value : e.getValue()) {
 prefixId(b).append(REQUEST_PREFIX).append(header).append(": ").append(value).append('\n');
 }
 }
 prefixId(b).append(REQUEST_PREFIX).append('\n');
 }

 private void printEntity(StringBuilder b, byte[] entity) throws IOException {
 if (entity.length == 0) {
 return;
 }
 b.append(new String(entity)).append("\n");
 }

 private final class Adapter implements ContainerResponseWriter {
 private final ContainerResponseWriter crw;

 private final boolean disableEntity;

 private long contentLength;

 private ContainerResponse response;

 private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

 private StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

 Adapter(ContainerResponseWriter crw) {
 this.crw = crw;
 this.disableEntity = rc.getFeature(FEATURE_LOGGING_DISABLE_ENTITY);
 }

 public OutputStream writeStatusAndHeaders(long contentLength, ContainerResponse response)
 throws IOException {
 printResponseLine(b, response);
 printResponseHeaders(b, response.getHttpHeaders());

 if (disableEntity) {
 logger.debug(b.toString());
 return crw.writeStatusAndHeaders(contentLength, response);
 } else {
 this.contentLength = contentLength;
 this.response = response;
 return this.baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 }
 }

 public void finish() throws IOException {
 if (!disableEntity) {
 byte[] entity = baos.toByteArray();

 try {
 MediaType mediaType =
 (MediaType) response.getHttpHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);

 if (mediaType != null && "application".equals(mediaType.getType())
 && "pdf".equals(mediaType.getSubtype()) == false) {
 printEntity(b, entity);
 } else {
 b.append("Binary content: ");
 if (mediaType != null && mediaType.getType() != null
 && mediaType.getSubtype() != null) {
 b.append(mediaType.getType());
 b.append("/");
 b.append(mediaType.getSubtype());
 }
 b.append("\n");
 }
 } catch (Exception e) {
 logger.error("Failed to log response", e);
 }

  //Output to log
 logger.debug(b.toString());

 // Write out the headers and buffered entity
 OutputStream out = crw.writeStatusAndHeaders(contentLength, response);
 out.write(entity);
 }
 crw.finish();
 }
 }

 public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
 setId();
 response.setContainerResponseWriter(new Adapter(response.getContainerResponseWriter()));
 return response;
 }

 private void printResponseLine(StringBuilder b, ContainerResponse response) {
 prefixId(b).append(NOTIFICATION_PREFIX).append("Server out-bound response").append('\n');
 prefixId(b).append(RESPONSE_PREFIX).append(Integer.toString(response.getStatus())).append('\n');
 }

 private void printResponseHeaders(StringBuilder b, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers) {
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> e : headers.entrySet()) {
 String header = e.getKey();
 for (Object value : e.getValue()) {
 prefixId(b).append(RESPONSE_PREFIX).append(header).append(": ")
 .append(ContainerResponse.getHeaderValue(value)).append('\n');
 }
 }
 prefixId(b).append(RESPONSE_PREFIX).append('\n');
 }

 }
```

Comment: The sad thing is, I actually built a filter for this at work, but currently have no access to it. What doesn't work with yours?

Comment: @Silverclaw. This filter has compilation issues with new jersey. I tried using the  solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550028/jersey-loggingfilter-with-log4j?rq=1 
But the new jersey is using Feature instead of filter.